# APP_ID is not defined on cordova-plugin-facebook4?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Installation:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
npm install -g cordova
vue create test
cd test
vue add cordova
// select Android + iOS + Browser
cd src-cordova
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="123456" --variable APP_NAME="test"
cd ..
npm run cordova-serve-browser
```

Returns (browser platform, Chrome developer console):

> APP_ID is not defined

Comment: Can you please share your exact error here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologise, it suddenly started working (I didn't even made any changes in the code). Weird!

For future reference, I think it should be installed once, delete the project, and create it again, in order to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per our discussion in a comment,

```
Ionic native plugins are not supported browser
```

It only supports device so you can not run the same plugin on the browser

You can Do for this

> 1. Check the Cordova in your code

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
       // Here code for your device so you can use the Cordova plugin here.
   }else{
       // Here code for your browser so you can use the Facebook JavaScript SDK 
   }
```

If you need any kind of help regards this feels free to write here.

Karmdip Joshi

Comment: @HristoTorbov, Please try this thing and check your application in browser and device both.

Comment: Actually, it's a Cordova plugin, Ionic is just using it. I'm testing it in Vue and it should support browser (as shown on https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/browser/README.md). I run both deviceready and cordova platform check.